# Crop PDF and Create PNG Using GhostScript

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, png, ghostscript

The application receives PDF with content that does not cover the entire page. Co-ordinates and dimensions of the content is also sent along with that data. Below is the sample command to create `cropped.png` from `target.pdf` where the content starts (X: 179, Y: 212) and the size (W: 600, H: 400).

```
gswin64c -q -sDEVICE=png16m -o "cropped.png" -dNumRenderingThreads=4 -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dLastPage=1 -c "<< /PageOffset [-179 -212] /Page >> setpagedevice" -r144 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -f "target.pdf"
```

It creates the PNG with the correct offset, however I could not find a way to define the area of the PDF that should be captured. In other words, the output must be a PNG that only contains the content within the given box.

GhostScript V9.22 is installed on Windows 10. I have ImageMagicK at my disposal too.

Is there a way to achieve this? Or am I approaching this incorrectly? Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You've offset the origin, but you haven't specified the media size, so the media size will be whatever it was in the original PDF file.

You need to add -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=600 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=400 -dFIXEDMEDIA, assuming that the media size you've given is correct. Obviously I can't tell where the actual white space is without seeing the original!

At 144 dpi there's no point in using -dNumRenderingThreads, realistically that's only useful at reasonably high resolution, at this resolution you'll just slow it down.

This:

-c "<< /PageOffset [-179 -212] /Page >> setpagedevice" -r144 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -f

Is incorrect, and I'm surprised it doesn't throw an error. When you specify -c everything after that, until the -f is treated as PostScript. The -r144 etc are not valid PostScript and I'd expect it to throw an error. You would be much better to move the -c "<< /PageOffset [-179 -212] /Page >> setpagedevice" -f to immediately before the input filename.

So I'd suggest your command line should be:

```
gswin64c -q -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=png16m -o "cropped.png" -dLastPage=1 -r144 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4  -dDEVICEWIDHTPOINTS=600 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=400 -dFIXEDMEDIA -c "<< /PageOffset [-179 -212] /Page >> setpagedevice" -f "target.pdf"
```

Comment: I did try using the -dDEVICEWIDHTPOINTS flags but did not work for me. Perhaps, I tried them incorrectly. I will try your approach. For now, I ended up using Magick.Net and it worked like a charm.

Thank you for your response!

Comment: You need to set -dFIXEDMEDIA as well as the width and height, or the PDF interpreter will reset the media size to be the the ones in the PDF file. If that doesn't work, well, I'd need to see your PDF file.